# Testing add multiple headers interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to Test an interceptor service like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()

export class ChacheCtrlInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor() { }

    intercept(req, next) {
        let httpCall = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set('Pragma', 'no-cache')
                                .set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
        });
        return next.handle(httpCall);
    }
}
```

This, just add this 2 headers to all the Http calls that I am doing in the application.

I know that for test if the interceptor adds the headers I have to do something like this:

```
it('should add Pragma header to request', () => {
        const req = new Http();
        expect(req.request.headers.has('Pragma')).toBeTruthy();
        expect(req.request.headers.get('Pragma')).toEqual('no-cache');
    });

it('should add Cache-Control header to request', () => {
        const req = new Http();
        expect(req.request.headers.has('Cache-Control')).toBeTruthy();
        expect(req.request.headers.get('Cache-Control')).toEqual('no-cache');
```

Any idea how can I coverage this code, I am new on karma testing :S

Comment: `ng test --code-coverage`. But you should first write a test that compiles, and that actually calls the method that you want to test.

Comment: Its an interceptor...it will be called. You really shouldn't be giving advice.

Comment: @TheBatman no. If you never send any request, the interceptor will never be called. The posted code never sends any request, so the interceptor will never be called. You really should think before posting nonsense.

Comment: Why should I when you've made an entire career out of it?